# Javascript constructor property not working when called

Tags: javascript, html, validation, constructor

I'm having trouble creating a constructor property. In the firebug console the error says `"telekomApp.validation.run is not a function"`. The `this.run()` function should be a property of `TelekomApp` constructor and I expect it too work as `telekomApp.validation.run()`, but it's not.

Please can you shed some light on this?

Many Thanks

JS:

```
(function(global) {

var TelekomApp = function() {

    this.validation = function() {

        var userNameField = document.getElementById("username-field"),
            passwordField = document.getElementById("password-field"),
            usernameMsg = document.getElementById("username-msg"),
            passwordMsg = document.getElementById("password-msg");

        this.run = function(tag) { // this method doesn't work...
            var o = this;
        };
      };
  };

  // make global
  global.TelekomApp = TelekomApp;

  // instanciate
  var telekomApp = new TelekomApp;

  // initialise validation...
  telekomApp.validation.run(document.getElementById("login-form"));

}(window));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="login">
        <p id="message"></p>
        <form id="login-form" action="#" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Please login using your username and password</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="username-field">Username <span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="username-field" placeholder="Type your username" />
                        <span id="username-msg"></span>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label for="password-field">Password <span>*</span></label>
                        <input type="password" id="password-field" placeholder="Type your password" />
                        <span id="password-msg"></span>
                    </li>

                    <li id="button">
                        <input type="submit" id="login-btn" value="Log In" />
                    </li>
                </ol>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function(global) {

var Validation = function() { //constructor for Validation

        var userNameField = document.getElementById("username-field"),
            passwordField = document.getElementById("password-field"),
            usernameMsg = document.getElementById("username-msg"),
            passwordMsg = document.getElementById("password-msg");

        this.run = function(tag) { // this method doesn't work...
            var o = this;
        };
};

var TelekomApp = function() {

    this.validation = new Validation();
  };

  // make global
  global.TelekomApp = TelekomApp;

  // instanciate
  var telekomApp = new TelekomApp;

  // initialise validation...
  telekomApp.validation.run(document.getElementById("login-form"));

}(window));
```

Answer (score 1):

`telekomApp.validation.run` would be added to the object when `telekomApp.validation` is called.

`this.validation = function() {` adds the function to the object but does not call it. Moreover `this.run = function(tag) {` adds `run` directly to `telekomApp`, not to `telekomApp.validation`.
A small change would do:

```
var Validation = function() {
  ...// your code here
}
this.validation = new Validation();
```